Postgres local for Guidewire cloud development
This is about using Postgres in local for Guidewire development to work around memory constraints and to deal with large data sets. Also thinking using postgres in local will make us closer  to production setup for troubleshooting.
My plan is to install a compatible PostgreSQL database version locally. This can be done either as an independent installation or using a Docker image. Connect the Guidewire application to the database using JDBC.
I haven't attempted this yet, but I'm planning to. Any one attempted this yet?

The Jasper support Matrix does indeed list Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL (13.9 or 12.9) as compatible for Local Development environments. I would think this implies that you would have to connect your local Jetty server to an AWS Aurora PostgreSQL instance, not a generic local PostgreSQL. You can certainly try to connect your Jetty server to a local PostgreSQL instance, and the documentation lists how to specify this in the database-config.xml (copied from documentation below):
Login required for link to work
https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/cc/202402/admin/admin/topics/database/r_hu1667728.html
<database name="ClaimCenterDatabase" dbtype="postgresql">
        <dbcp-connection-pool jdbc-url="string" max-idle="200" max-total="integer"/>
</database>

I would imagine there would be a little bit of configuration you would need to do to your local PostgreSQL DB before starting the Jetty server such as creating the ccUser (for ClaimCenter) and setting the correct permissions. There aren't really any details like with the on-premise versions of what you need to configure in the DB server so this will probably take some tinkering on your end to get it to work. Good luck.
I should also note that I have not done this myself and I would imagine there is a chance this may not work at all. So decide how much effort you'd like to devote to this wisely.

I can say that I've seen multiple implementations use PostgreSQL for local development.  In all the cases I'm aware of that was a local installation, not a connection to an AWS-hosted instance.  I don't know how you'd make that work as the GW Cloud instances wouldn't be available for an external connection like that, so it would have to be a customer-owned AWS account for that to work.

Thanks for the clarification Marty that others have used the local PostgreSQL. On the question of connecting to an Aurora PostgreSQL, yes that would have to be the customer's own AWS environment, not GWCP. Several customers I have worked with have their own AWS instances because there is a design pattern for CDA uses customer S3 buckets in addition to the GWCP CDA S3 buckets, so I assumed some percentage of customers will have their own AWS tenant separate from GWCP.

jdbc-url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/edollin?user=edollin&password=LizziePhilip65!"

I have lightly used postgresql locally.  This is my configuration from database-config.xml.  I was able to quote and bind a policy, but had some issues with importing xml data.  You have to get the charset correct when you create your database.
<database
    autoupgrade="full"
    dbtype="postgresql"
    env="{localenvname}"
    name="PolicyCenterDatabase">
    <dbcp-connection-pool
        jdbc-url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{dbname}?user={username};password={password}"
        max-idle="200"
        max-total="200">
        <reset-tool-params system-password="gw"/>
    </dbcp-connection-pool>
</database>


I actually add a file called config.postgres.properties and set my environment variable to postgres using -Dgw.pc.env=postgres
then in the properties file i added
suite.SUITE_PC_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8180/pc
config.CONFIG_PC_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8180/pc
suite.SUITE_CC_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8080/cc
config.CONFIG_CC_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8080/cc
suite.SUITE_BC_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8580/bc
config.CONFIG_BC_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8580/bc
suite.SUITE_CM_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8280/ab
config.CONFIG_CM_PRODUCT_URL=http\://localhost:8280/ab
database.DATABASE_AURORA_ENV=postgres
database.DATABASE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{DBName}?user={DBUser}&password={pwd}

this way you do not need to modify database-config.xml
